# Indentation Tex

Tags: math-mode, indentation

I need to put the text as follows, but i don't see how.
[image]

Please help me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
$$\llbracket \Phi_{1}(\vec{a})\wedge\Phi_{2}(\vec{a})\rrbracket \in U \textrm{ iff } \llbracket \Phi_{1}(\vec{a})\rrbracket\cap \llbracket\Phi_{2}(\vec{a})\rrbracket \in U$$
$$\textrm{    iff}$$
\end{document}
```

can not solve with `\textrm`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you show us what you have tried so far in the form of  a MWE.

Comment: you most likely need a tab or tabular environment you need to provide enough of a small example.tex with those characters above for others to suggest which one is best for your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `align*` environment from `amsmath` to get the alignment, and `\DeclareMathOperator{\Iff}{iff}` to make a new macro for iff.  Note the `&` which indicates the alignment point, and the `\\` to start a new line in the `align*`.

In general you should never use `$$ .. $$` for display math in LaTeX, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Iff}{iff}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\llbracket \Phi_{1}(\vec{a})\wedge\Phi_{2}(\vec{a})\rrbracket \in U & \Iff \llbracket \Phi_{1}(\vec{a})\rrbracket\cap \llbracket\Phi_{2}(\vec{a})\rrbracket \in U \\
& \Iff \llbracket\Phi_{i}(\vec{a})\rrbracket \in U \text{ for } i=1,2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve it differently by using a table.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, array}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

\[ \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1ex}
\begin{array}{r!{\text{ iff }} >{\displaystyle}l}
\llbracket \Phi_{1}(\vec{a})\enspace \text{\&}\enspace \Phi_{2}(\vec{a})\rrbracket \in U & \llbracket \Phi_{1}(\vec{a})\rrbracket\cap \llbracket\Phi_{2}(\vec{a})\rrbracket \in U \\
& \llbracket\Phi_{i}(\vec{a})\rrbracket \in U \quad\text{for } i=1,2 \\
 & \prod_{i\in I}A_i/U \vDash \phi_i(\vec{a}/U)\quad\text{for } i=1,2 \\
 & \prod_{i\in I}A_i/U \vDash \phi_1(\vec{a}/U) \enspace \text{\&}\enspace \phi_2(\vec{a}/U)
\end{array}
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image]